# Dynamically change table background color based on value

Tags: html, jsp, jstl

I have table which is being populted from database and I need to apply background color for each row which is also coming from dtabase.  my code is below Im not sure what Im doing wrong but its not working. HELP!

[image]

```
       <tbody> 
  <tr> 
  <c:forEach items="${summary}" var="summary" 
  style='background-color:<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>;'>


 <tr>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.eventDesc}"  /></td>
  <td><c:out value="${summary.labelNbr}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.origin}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.senderName}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.receiverName}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.receiptDate}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.loadDate}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.forecastIsc}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.actualIsc}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.country}" /></td>
 <td><c:out value="${summary.source}" /></td>
 <td><input type="checkbox" value=""></td>
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

Comment: There is no single reference to jQuery in that question.

Comment: i would use class names instead of inline styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I finally figured it out. Since Im pulling the color from database table following code works fine:

```
<td bgcolor='<c:out value="${summary.color}"></c:out>'>
    <c:out value="${summary.eventDesc}" />
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you really have to resort to using the colors from the database, then you have to add an inline style to each `<tr>` or `<td>`

---

I would suggest adding a css class to your `<tr>` element for each color and then write your css rules like so

`tr.class-1 > td {
  background-color: yellow
}`

`tr.class-2 > td {
  background-color: red
}`

`tr.class-3 > td {
  background-color: green
}`

Comment: Thanks, But would that work if each row is populated randomly i.e first 3 rows can be yellow n then following on pink and so on.

Comment: I also tried adding the color to TD element but getting an error <td style='background-color:<c:out value="${summary.color}">><c:out value="${summary.eventDesc}"  /></td>

Answer (score 0):

Try this (it will reduce number of lines in your code):

```
<c:forEach items="${summary}" var="summary">
<tr style='background-color: ${summary.color}'>
<td></td>
<td></td>
<td></td>
</tr>
</c:forEach>
```